# While loops conditions and setInterval()

Tags: javascript

I want to preface this by saying I have very little knowledge of JS as you'll probably be able to tell, I also wasn't sure what to title this.

Anyway, I'm trying to make a simple script where it counts up to 30 minutes and then at 30 minutes returns a message by using a while loop. However, I want the condition where heliTime =! endTime to only run every minute. I can get the script to run every minute however in runs the entire function each minute instead of just one check.

```js
setInterval(function arran() {
    var startTime = 0;
    var minutes = 1000 * 60;
    //var seconds = 1000;
    var heliTime = startTime
    var endTime = 30 * minutes;
    var messageCount = 0;

while (heliTime !== endTime) {
  var messageCount = messageCount + 1;
  console.log("No heli yet! " + messageCount);
  var heliTime = heliTime + minutes;
}
return console.log("Heli should be arriving soon!");
},60 * 1000);
```

The messageCount variable is just debug so that can be ignored, any help with my problem would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that measuring real time by the frequence of callbacks by setInterval as Tobbe Widner suggest seems to me as a strange idea. I think it is better to use some explicit time source such as

```
function runDelayedWithProgress(waitIntervalSeconds, delayedAction, progressIntervalSeconds, progressAction) {
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  var iid = setInterval(function() {
     var curTime = new Date().getTime()
     var elapsedSeconds = (curTime - startTime)/1000;
     if(elapsedSeconds >= waitIntervalSeconds) {
        clearInterval(iid);
        delayedAction();
     }
     else {
       progressAction(Math.round(elapsedSeconds));
     }
  }, progressIntervalSeconds*1000);
}

runDelayedWithProgress(30*60, function() {
      console.log("Heli should be arriving soon!")
   }, 
   60, function(elapsed){
     console.log("No heli yet! " + elapsed);
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly thanks. Not familiar with most of this but I'll have to look into it. The reason I tried to do it the way I did is primarily down to lack of knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. Of course you're right about the real-time processing. I'm actually a little ashamed of myself, because I should know that (I was involved in programming graphic buffer handling, where real-time processing is, lets say, very important xD)